# How to use Auth0 Authorisation with Gin framework?

Tags: go, backend, auth0

I'm trying to use Auth0 authorisation for my Golang (Gin) backend, to limit requests to authorised parties, I've done this for Django previously, but I can't get it to work with Gin and Golang.

I've tried every guide I can find, none work. Including the auth0 docs [found here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/golang).

My Main.go

```
package main

import (
   "StatsMicro/controller"
   "StatsMicro/middleware"
   "StatsMicro/models"
   "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
   println("HERE")
   var r *gin.Engine = gin.Default()
   r.Use(middleware.EnsureValidToken())
   println("pasted engine")
   models.ConnectDatabase()
   println("PAST ENDPOINTS")
   r.POST("/update", controller.AliveUpdate)
   r.POST("/ErrorCreate", controller.ErrorCreate)
   r.POST("/postCreate", controller.PsotCreated)

   r.GET("/user", controller.AliveGet)
   r.GET("/activeAll", controller.ActiveallTotal)
   r.GET("/postAll", controller.PostAllTotal)
   r.GET("/errorTotal", controller.ErrorAllTotal)
   r.GET("/error", controller.ErrorGet)
   r.GET("/post", controller.PostGet)
   err := r.Run("127.0.0.1:2003")
   if err != nil {
      return
   }

}
```

My JWT.go:

```
package middleware

import (
   "context"
   "log"
   "net/http"
   "net/url"
   "os"
   "time"

   "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/v2"
   "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/v2/jwks"
   "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/v2/validator"
)

// CustomClaims contains custom data we want from the token.
type CustomClaims struct {
   Scope string `json:"scope"`
}

// Validate does nothing for this example, but we need
// it to satisfy validator.CustomClaims interface.
func (c CustomClaims) Validate(ctx context.Context) error {
   return nil
}

// EnsureValidToken is a middleware that will check the validity of our JWT.
func EnsureValidToken() func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
   issuerURL, err := url.Parse("https://" + os.Getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN") + "/")
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Failed to parse the issuer url: %v", err)
   }

   provider := jwks.NewCachingProvider(issuerURL, 5*time.Minute)

   jwtValidator, err := validator.New(
      provider.KeyFunc,
      validator.RS256,
      issuerURL.String(),
      []string{os.Getenv("AUTH0_AUDIENCE")},
      validator.WithCustomClaims(
         func() validator.CustomClaims {
            return &CustomClaims{}
         },
      ),
      validator.WithAllowedClockSkew(time.Minute),
   )
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Failed to set up the jwt validator")
   }

   errorHandler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
      log.Printf("Encountered error while validating JWT: %v", err)

      w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
      w.Write([]byte(`{"message":"Failed to validate JWT."}`))
   }

   middleware := jwtmiddleware.New(
      jwtValidator.ValidateToken,
      jwtmiddleware.WithErrorHandler(errorHandler),
   )

   return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
      return middleware.CheckJWT(next)
   }
}
```

The error produced when I run main.go is as follows:

```
main.go:13:8: cannot use middleware.EnsureValidToken() (value of type func(next http.Handler) http.Handler) as type gin.HandlerFunc in argument to r.Use
```

To my understanding, this is because it's not a valid GinHandlerFunc. If so, how do I turn it into a valid gin handler function?

I've attempted to use multiple guides on the web. Some of them are for very old versions and others just don't work. Given the importance of this, I'd rather not use an old version.

[Dev.To guide](https://dev.to/ksivamuthu/auth0-jwt-middleware-in-go-gin-web-framework-37mj) - Couldn't get this to work

[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/err0r500/00c50d45a5337058c4c732206457bd64) - Very old version

[Medium](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-build-a-web-app-with-go-gin-and-react-cffdc473576) - Couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

your method EnsureValidToken needs to return a gin.HandlerFunc. You might want to have a look at the Wrap function in https://github.com/gwatts/gin-adapter/blob/master/adapter.go#L62 (although it might be better to even use that module).

Works like this:

```
func EnsureValidToken() gin.HandlerFunc {
    issuerURL, err := url.Parse("https://" + os.Getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN") + "/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse the issuer url: %v", err)
    }

    provider := jwks.NewCachingProvider(issuerURL, 5*time.Minute)

    jwtValidator, err := validator.New(
        provider.KeyFunc,
        validator.RS256,
        issuerURL.String(),
        []string{os.Getenv("AUTH0_AUDIENCE")},
        validator.WithCustomClaims(
            func() validator.CustomClaims {
                return &CustomClaims{}
            },
        ),
        validator.WithAllowedClockSkew(time.Minute),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to set up the jwt validator")
    }

    errorHandler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
        log.Printf("Encountered error while validating JWT: %v", err)

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"message":"Failed to validate JWT."}`))
    }

    middleware := jwtmiddleware.New(
        jwtValidator.ValidateToken,
        jwtmiddleware.WithErrorHandler(errorHandler),
    )

    return adapter.Wrap(middleware.CheckJWT)
}
```

To apply the middleware:

```
r.Use(middleware.EnsureValidToken())
```